# Angular directive with two way binding, filter and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a directive that accepts an array of objects and run ng-repeat to render them.

```
app.directive("rockers", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            items : '='
        },
        template : '<div>'+
                       '<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} Rocks!</span>'+
                    '</div>'

    };
});
```

In the controller, I set the scope with opjects:

```
app.controller("appController", function($scope){
    $scope.scopedItems = [{name:"Aanny"}, {name:"Bonny"}, {name:"Danny"}];
});
```

And then, to call the directive I pass the scopedItems with filter, like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    Rockers: 
    <rockers items="scopedItems | filter:{name:'Bonny'}"></rockers>
</div>
```

Without using the filters in the HTML, everything works fine. When passing the filter I still get the results I want, but I'm also getting this error: "**Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**"

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q37gC/) to recreate the error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can pass filtered data to directive like a string:

```
<rockers items="{{ scopedItems | filter:{name:'Bonny'} }}"></rockers>
```

and parse it value to object it directive:

```
app.directive("rockers", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        scope : {},
        link:function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.items = JSON.parse(attr.items);
        },
        template : '<div>'+
                       '<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}} Rocks!</span>'+
                    '</div>'

    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34ag7/4/

Comment: You are close! It works, but consider filtering with bound data, where 'Bonny' is something that comes from the scope. See example in http://jsfiddle.net/F4kPQ/

Comment: require model in the preceding example is not needed. http://jsfiddle.net/aU3z8/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass rocker name into directive by attribute and filter it there:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    Rockers: 
    <rockers name="Bonny" items="scopedItems"></rockers>
</div>
```

And in directive:

```
app.directive("rockers", function(){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            items : '='
        },
        link:function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.filteredItems = function(filterItemName){
                return scope.items.filter(function(item){
                    return item.name == filterItemName;
                })
            };
            scope.filteredItem = scope.filteredItems(attr.name);
        },


        template : '<div>'+
                       '<span ng-repeat="item in filteredItem">{{item.name}} Rocks!</span>'+
                    '</div>'

    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3dc9/39/

Comment: The point of this is that I don't know by what the programmer who will use my code will be filtering. This is not just filter, it's also happens in orderBy. I want the programmer to take care of it since the directive isn't suppose to know in advance what will be the final list he should display.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) in a custom filter to return the calculated value unless the input value changes.

See this example: [Memoizing Angular filters to stop digest errors](http://www.terrencewatson.com/2014/06/28/memoize/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution involving adding another two-way bound scope variable to the directive and filtering inside the directive template instead of inside the html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="find"><br>
    Rockers: 
    <rockers items="scopedItems" filter="find"></rockers>
</div>
```

Angular gives digest errors when a filtered array expression is passed in as a two-way bound directive scope variable. By using the filter attribute, you can filter anything you type in the input field, or use a $scope object to defined your filter e.g. `$scope.find = {name: 'Bonny'};` You could even use a scope filter function or pre-defined filter, anything you would pass into a real filter expression will work because of the two-way binding.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("appController", function($scope){
    $scope.scopedItems = [{name:"Aanny"}, {name:"Bonny"}, {name:"Danny"}];
});

app.directive("rockers", function($filter){
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            items : '=',
            filter: '='
        },
        template : '<div>'+
                       '<span ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filter">{{item.name}} Rocks!</span>'+
                    '</div>'
    };
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2jhswna6/